# Shift Register in verilog

Tags: verilog, vlsi

I have designed a serial in parallel out shift register as input register for an encoder

```
module ShiftRegister_SIPO(clk, in, out);
input clk,in;
output [3:0] out;
reg [3:0] tmp;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
tmp = {tmp[2:0], in};
end
assign PO = tmp;
endmodule
```

how do I retain the value once the desired parallel out data is got , even with clk=1? Because even after the output data is got the value keeps shifting. For example ,if i give
**Part  of testbench**

```
in=1;
#10
in=0;
#10
in=1;
#10
in=1;

#5 clk=~clk;
```

I get 1011 at the 4th clock cycle , but the value then keeps shifting. Can i retain it as 1011 for the remaining period also, still keeping the clk=1.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you example the value will be shifting every positive edge of the clock. In order to prevent it from shifting under some circumstances you need a way to enable or disable shifting. For example:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
   if (enable)
      tmp <= {tmp[2:0], in};
end
```

So, controlling the `enable` signal you can control shifting. If its value is low, then no shifting will happen and the value of 'tmp' will remain unchanged till you enable it again.